# It's not clear which file to import for '@import

Tags: .net

Just got this error trying to run this project.

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error 0   It's not clear which file to import for '@import
>   "../../variables"'. Candidates:   ../../_variables.scss
>   ../../_variables.css Please delete or rename all but one of these
>   files.
>     Web C:\temp\eShopOnWeb-master\eShopOnWeb-master\src\Web\wwwroot\css\basket\basket-status\basket-status.component.scss   1

```
@import '../../variables'; --> error?

.esh-basketstatus {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    transition: all $animation-speed-default;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was pretty easy. 
Error message simply indicated it could not find the scss file path.

```
 @import '../../variables.scss';
```